# Internet Explorer 9 with primefaces and yaml

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces, yaml

I have a project using primefaces 5 and yaml. When I tested it on local, everything worked fine. In my company we use IE9 and the newest Google Chrome. When I deployed the application on an application server and tried to view it with IE9 it looks very crappy. When I use IE9 to access via localhost I have the possibility to activate/deactivate the compatibility mode - on the server not. When I access e.g. the primefaces showcase page there is also the comp. mode button.

How can I give possibility to show/hide this button?

I tried to add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

to my head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        >

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Invoice Manager</title>
    <!-- Mobile viewport optimisation -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="yaml/core/base.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="yaml/navigation/hlist.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="yaml/screen/typography.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="yaml/screen/screen-FULLPAGE-layout.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="yaml/print/print.css" />

    <h:outputScript name="yaml/core/js/yaml-focusfix.js" />
</h:head>
```

But always it looks very bad with IE9 and all primefaces components don't work. Only via localhost everything works fine. Is there a possibility to handle this?

Comment: Could you be more accurate about "it looks very bad" ? Do you mean a style/CSS issue ? Also, what mean "primefaces components don't work". Which component ? What behaviour ? Possible javascript issue here.

Comment: Sorry for that. For example I use my own fonts in the webinterface. These are only shown if I access via localhost. But also most of the coloured divs are not in the correct color. So I mean mostly CSS issues. The most of the primefaces components don't work when accessing from public server, e.g. the tabView, checkboxes with ajax, dialogs, ... It is all like if you access the showcase of primefaces and activate the compatibility mode.

Comment: You seem to have several problems. For the font issue, you should use web fonts. If you use local true type fonts, rendering is impossible for external web clients. For other CSS issues, use inspector tools (ie F12 in chrome or FF). Inspect elements and check their styles and computed styles. CSS order is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place this meta tag as first tag of `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
```

It should prevent compatibility mode in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but the problem is that meta element must come before all other entries in the head section except for the title. See this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can accomplish this by using a facet and naming it "first". This has a special meaning to the renderer which will put its contents before others.

```
<f:facet name="first">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</f:facet>
```